# Django admin - handling permissions of many to many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have 2 models as follows. As there is a many to many relation between the models, django created the required table (clientreport) and the table's permissions can be set using django admin's group permission's tab. (see screenshot)[image: django admin ss]

```
class Report(models.Model):
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

On django admin I granted change permissions to a specific user group (e.g. group_a) on Report model. I did NOT grant any permissions on clientreport model.

My desired output is, a group_a user can change is_visible field of any Report instance but could not change/delete client X reports (or clientreport).

However even if there is no actual table reference between Report and Client models, a group_a user can still edit client-reports from django admin panel. (see screenshot)[image: ss 2]

Is this really intended? If so, how can I get my desired goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict access to certain fields by certain rights, you can use the [ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method.

Usage example:

```
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj = None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name=groupname).exists():
            return ('field1', 'field2')
        else:
            return super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```